# C# add items to listview not working

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

```
private void showResultsList()
{
    IWebElement table = resultFinder.FindElementById("records");
    IList<IWebElement> trElements = table.FindElements(By.TagName("tr"));
    IList<IWebElement> tdElements;
    IList<IWebElement> aElements = table.FindElements(By.TagName("a"));

    mainWindow.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
    {
        ListView listView = (ListView)mainWindow.FindName("Search_ResultsList");
        ItemCollection resultsListItems = listView.Items;
        listView.Items.Clear();


        for (int i = 0; i < trElements.Count; i++)
        {
            IWebElement trElement = trElements[i];
            tdElements = trElement.FindElements(By.TagName("td"));
            aElements = trElement.FindElements(By.TagName("a"));
            string index = (i + 1).ToString();
            string text = tdElements[2].Text;
            // this line removes the last part of the content, which says "Aggiungi ai preferiti"
            string result = text.Substring(0, text.LastIndexOf('\n'));
            string hyperLink = aElements[0].GetAttribute("href");

            resultsListItems.Add(new ResultsListItem { Index = index, Result = result, HyperLink = hyperLink });
        }
    });
}
```

**XAML file**

```
<ListView Name="Search_ResultsList" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="886" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="440" BorderBrush="#FF707070">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="N." Width="30" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Index}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Result" Width="387" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Result}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

**ResultsListItem class**

```
class ResultsListItem : ListViewItem
{
    public string Index { get; set; }
    public string Result { get; set; }
    public string HyperLink { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to show this list into a ListView object by adding the ResultsListItem to the collection of items. When I run the program the list doesn't show the content of the listItems, just a list of empty items. What do I do wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your headers are displayed correctly? Could you provide the code of the `ResultsListItem` class?

Comment: Sure, I post it in my question

Comment: I found the error also thank to you!!! I shouldn't inherit the ResultsListItem from ListViewItem. Thanks to everyone who helped me!! =)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing to set the ItemsSource to the Listview,try this

```
 Search_ResultsList.ItemsSource = resultsListItems;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use DataGrid instead, if you want to show tabular data in the view -

**Code Behind**

```
private void showResultsListWithDataGrid()
  {
    List<ResultsListItem> listItem = new List<ResultsListItem>();
    for(int i=1; i<=10; i++)
    {
        listItem.Add(new ResultsListItem
        {
            Index = "index" + i,
            Result = "result" + i,
            HyperLink = "hyperlink" + i
        });
    }
    this.dataGrid.ItemsSource = listItem; //datagrid should be declared on the xaml file
}
```

please see details on - [DataGrid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

As you have already noticed your ResultsListItem should *not* inherit from `ListViewItem`:

```
public class ResultsListItem
{
    public string Index { get; set; }
    public string Result { get; set; }
    public string HyperLink { get; set; }
}
```

The reason for this is that an implicit `ListViewItem` container is automatically generated for each item in the `Items`/`ItemsSource` collection of the `ListView` that is not a `ListViewItem`.

If you add a `ListViewItem` to the `Items`/`ItemsSource`, no container is generated and that's why you don't see any values in your `ListView`.

Also, it doesn't make any sense for a data object to inherit from a UI type.